# Dynamically injecting views with PRISM and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing application that will visualize some data. I will create custom user controls ( graphs,charts,tables ) for visualization. Now,to simplify it let's say, I want to have architecture like this:

1. MainWindow is a tabbed window + is has "Options" button
2. When user  click "Options" the new window pops up, when he can select the data he wants to see, choose the method (graph,table, etc...) how it will be visualized and what is very important select the tab where he wants this graph/table to show up ( they can appear in MainWindow one after another, in a "Wrap Panel" manner)
3. Furthermore I want also this functionality, that when user closes Options window, he can resize this graphs/tables he just chose to appear, he can switch its places by mouse dragging etc.

Now, can you advise me which technique/elements of Wpf/Prism I should use to accomplish injecting these user controls (views) in the way I described above.
Greetings

Answer (score 1):

#### The Fastest Possible Way to Achieve Your Objectives

1. [Read the documentation](http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/Introduction.html), carefully.  *All of it.*  Then, read it again.
2. Download the [WPF samples](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf).  Run each example, in order (the examples each build upon concepts from the previous examples).  Examine the code.  Make sure you understand how each example works before moving on to the next one.

When you have completed those two tasks, you should have a very good understanding of what you need to do to accomplish your specific task within the context of Prism.

How do I know? Because this is what I did.

Comment: So since you are an expert, maybe you can help a a little more? Because asnwers like "read the documentation" are not very helpful I must say :( I am going through Prism samples already, but I wouldn't  mind Is someone more experienced than I am shared with me some simple solution. I don't want to make this application more complicated that it needs to be ;p

Comment: Then your question needs to be more specific.  The question that you asked is in the documentation, in its entirety.  There's no shortcut way I can give you; you need to know all of it.  The good news is that "all of it" isn't really all that much.